# Как анимировать блок при убирании мышки (без JS)

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть такой блок(с месяцами), который появляется, если навести на месяц в календаре, я смог анимировать отведение мышки с блока тем, что я ей задавал по умолчанию анимацию исчезания, вот `ccs` код:

```css
.month_wrapper { /* Это блок с месяцами */
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: monthNoVisible .3s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.calendar__month:hover .month_wrapper { /* При наведении на месяц,
задавать анимацию появления блока с выбором месяца */
    animation-name: monthVisible;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes monthVisible { /* Анимация появления */
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

@keyframes monthNoVisible { /* Анимация исчезания */
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    100% {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

**Проблема в том**, что при загрузке странице **анимация исчезания автоматически срабатывает**, так как я её задал блоку. Возможно ли это решить без `js`, не отлавливая события мыши?

```css
:root {
  --gray: #333333;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.calendar {
 max-width: 500px;
}

.calendar__date {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}

.calendar__month {
 margin-right: 5px;
 display: block;
}

.month_wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 600;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 border: 1px solid black;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 animation: monthNoVisible .3s ease-in-out;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.month_wrapper .month {
 padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
}

.month_wrapper .month:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.month_wrapper .month:hover {
 color: white;
 background-color: var(--gray);
}

@keyframes monthVisible {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: visible;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 }
}

@keyframes monthNoVisible {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 }
 99% {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: visible;
 }
 100% {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

.calendar__month:hover .month_wrapper {
 animation-name: monthVisible;
 cursor: pointer;
}



/**************************************************************

Ниже код, который не участвует в анимации 

******************************************************************/



.calendar__top {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 color: white;
 background-color: var(--gray);
}

.calendar__right, .calendar__left {
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.day__week {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding: 6px 0;
 border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
}

.day__month {
 border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
 border-top: 0;
}

.week {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.week > div {
 background-color: #f3f2f2;
 flex: 1;
 height: 40px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 font-size: 19px;
}

.week > div:not(:last-child) {
 border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.week:not(:last-child) div {
 border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

div.today {
 background-color: #ee5728;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
 <div class="calendar__top">
  <div class="calendar__left">«</div>
  <div class="calendar__date">
   <span class="calendar__month">
        <span>Ноябрь</span>
    <div class="month_wrapper">
     <div class="month">Январь</div>
     <div class="month">Февраль</div>
     <div class="month">Март</div>
     <div class="month">Апрель</div>
     <div class="month">Май</div>
     <div class="month">Июнь</div>
     <div class="month">Июль</div>
     <div class="month">Август</div>
     <div class="month">Сентябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Октябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Ноябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Декабрь</div>
    </div>
   </span>
   <span class="calendar__year">2019</span>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar__right">»</div>
 </div>
 <div class="day__week">
  <div>Пн</div>
  <div>Вт</div>
  <div>Ср</div>
  <div>Чт</div>
  <div>Пт</div>
  <div>Сб</div>
  <div>Вс</div>
 </div>
 <div class="day__month">
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы слышали про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ поправил, нормально?

Comment: Ну явно лучше :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что Вы в решении Вашей задачи сильно перемудрили. Если вопрос только в том, чтобы блок плавно появлялся по ховеру и плавно исчезал, анимация вообще не нужна - достаточно свойства transition:

```css
:root {
  --gray: #333333;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.calendar {
 max-width: 500px;
}

.calendar__date {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}

.calendar__month {
 margin-right: 5px;
 display: block;
}

.month_wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 600;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px black;
 border: 1px solid black;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.month_wrapper .month {
 padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
}

.month_wrapper .month:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.month_wrapper .month:hover {
 color: white;
 background-color: var(--gray);
}
.calendar__month:hover .month_wrapper {
 visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
}


/**************************************************************

Ниже код, который не участвует в анимации 

******************************************************************/



.calendar__top {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 color: white;
 background-color: var(--gray);
}

.calendar__right, .calendar__left {
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.day__week {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding: 6px 0;
 border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
}

.day__month {
 border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
 border-top: 0;
}

.week {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.week > div {
 background-color: #f3f2f2;
 flex: 1;
 height: 40px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 font-size: 19px;
}

.week > div:not(:last-child) {
 border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.week:not(:last-child) div {
 border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

div.today {
 background-color: #ee5728;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
 <div class="calendar__top">
  <div class="calendar__left">«</div>
  <div class="calendar__date">
   <span class="calendar__month">
        <span>Ноябрь</span>
    <div class="month_wrapper">
     <div class="month">Январь</div>
     <div class="month">Февраль</div>
     <div class="month">Март</div>
     <div class="month">Апрель</div>
     <div class="month">Май</div>
     <div class="month">Июнь</div>
     <div class="month">Июль</div>
     <div class="month">Август</div>
     <div class="month">Сентябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Октябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Ноябрь</div>
     <div class="month">Декабрь</div>
    </div>
   </span>
   <span class="calendar__year">2019</span>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar__right">»</div>
 </div>
 <div class="day__week">
  <div>Пн</div>
  <div>Вт</div>
  <div>Ср</div>
  <div>Чт</div>
  <div>Пт</div>
  <div>Сб</div>
  <div>Вс</div>
 </div>
 <div class="day__month">
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я такой вариант как раз сделал, но где-то не дописал свойство и подумал, что это не работает)